# Hamburger menu not opening (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a nav bar I got from the documentation on BootStrap. When I collapse it to a mobile version, the hamburger menu shows up, but clicking on it doesn't do anything. Here is the code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #000000;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Salman's Website</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="electric.html">Electric<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="gasoline.html">Gasoline<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="hybrid.html">Hybrid<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
```

I did put the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in the head tag too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably not imported the `javascript` files of bootstrap. So if you import it, it's work well:

```html
<!-- IMPORT BOOTSTRAP STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- IMPORT BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #000000;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Salman's Website</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="electric.html">Electric<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="gasoline.html">Gasoline<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="hybrid.html">Hybrid<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: You absolute genius. I'm new to this and obviously dumb enough to see I completely forgot the JS scripts. Thank you so much!!!